# Repeated Values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So I am trying to fetch pageviews and Orders from two tables Transaction and PagViews . When I run this query :

```
   EXPLAIN
   SELECT 
   pv.productid,
   EXTRACT(week from pv.dt) as WEEK,
   COUNT(pv.productid) as PageViews,
   COUNT(distinct t.orderid) as Orders, 
   AVG(pv.numreviews) avg_numreviews
   FROM PageView pv 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Transaction t 
   ON pv.productid = t.productid 
   AND t.client ='xyz'
   WHERE 
   pv.client ='xyz' 
   AND pv.dt BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-06-30'
   GROUP BY pv.productid, WEEK
   ORDER BY WEEK asc ;
```

I get few values right , but for some productids the data is like this :

productid      WEEK       PageView   Orders   Avg. Reviews

7843             1        968           11        0

Basically the pageview value should be 88 , instead of 968 for week 1.

I do get that the it is counting the same data 11 times !

Can someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong in this query or what is missing . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ratio of `PageViews` to `Orders` count then following should do it.

```
SELECT 
   pv.productid,
   EXTRACT(week from pv.dt) as WEEK,
   COUNT(pv.productid) as PageViews,
   (COUNT(pv.productid) / COUNT(distinct t.orderid)) as PageViewsDividedByOrderCount,
   COUNT(distinct t.orderid) as Orders, 
   AVG(pv.numreviews) avg_numreviews
   FROM PageView pv 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Transaction t 
   ON pv.productid = t.productid 
   AND t.client ='xyz'
   WHERE 
   pv.client ='xyz' 
   AND pv.dt BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-06-30'
   GROUP BY pv.productid, WEEK
   ORDER BY WEEK asc ;
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I am looking for. I just wanted to know why Pageviews values are so high , why the data is getting repeated.

Comment: @AshwinSingh because `COUNT` is done per all records selected and not one row. You have 11 order rows, and 968 product rows.

Comment: Oh ok , then I should be using a count distinct correct ?

Comment: `COUNT DISTINCT` will give you count of UNIQUE values. If you will remove distinct from order you will get 968.

Comment: @AshwinSingh and 88 is what? Views per Week?

Comment: Yes, its the views per week

Comment: @AshwinSingh You will have to `JOIN` to `WEEK` then. Where date of that week would overlap with time in pageview, but this is completely separate question at this point. I suggest you search/create new question on how to JOIN on overlapping dates to get weeks.